# prepending "m" to a pandas string column yields the error "ufunc 'isnat' is only defined for datetime and timedelta."

Tags: python, pandas

```
xx= pd.DataFrame(dict(a = ['a','b']))
"m" + xx['a'].astype(str)
```

yields

```
TypeError: ufunc 'isnat' is only defined for datetime and timedelta.
```

but yet

```
"monkeys" + xx['a'].astype(str)
```

yields as expected:

```
0    monkeysa
1    monkeysb
Name: a, dtype: object
```

What in the fresh heck is going on here and what does the `m` signify?

This is python 3.7.5 with pandas==0.25.2

Comment: Hmmm, might have been a bug that was fixed, the first works in `pd.__version__ == '1.2.0'`.

Comment: works in 1.0.5, python 3.6

Comment: I would suggest debugging step by step... Try `"m" + xx['a']`

Comment: Ah wow, nope this was exactly an issue with the 'm' being assumed to represent something like 'minutes' for timedelta, and was fixed: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/28658. This should be fixed on anything > 1.0